# 403 Error "Forbidden" In Google Apps Script (GAS)

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

A few weeks ago embedded Google Drive links stopped working in  elements in HTML. I have a program running in Google Apps Script that uses a google drive link that is shared with everyone who has the link (so permissions shouldn't be an issue) yet I now get a 403 "Forbidden" error when the image is embedded.

I have included the  code below, which throws the 403 error, as well as images of both the sharing settings and an image of the error in the console.

`<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1MXPTFUYQrR5q4p4HHISil0WQTXsE3mmG">`

[image: Console Error]
[image: Share screen in Google Drive]

I have tried using multiple accounts, incognito browsers, multiple devices, and changing the format of the drive link inside the  src, all without success.

Not sure what changed, or what is going wrong, because the link works properly when used normally, but throws the 403 error when embedded in HTML.

Comment: Apparently, there is a new update that is related to this issue. You may refer to [this thread](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/253003338/images-from-google-drive-in-embedded-html-no-longer-working?hl=en) and [this update announcement article](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html)

Comment: You may want to embed the image using an iframe.

Comment: You could store in the image in your Google Photo Library or perhaps conver it to an imageuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PatrickdC is 100% correct, thanks for the info Patrick!

The [post he linked](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html) to explains the issue well enough.

This post was the result of a support call with the folks over at Google Drive, who suggested that I post on stackoverflow when we ran out of ideas.

Thanks everyone for your help!